# how to get selected username from dropdown list to be the var for URL

Tags: php, html

How do i get the selected variable to show up in the URL from the 
 `<select>` ...

my code is:

```
print "<select name=\"assignedby\" multiple size=\"10\">";

while ($data = dbResult($qh)) {
        print "<option name=\"$data[name]\"";
        print ">$data[name]</option>\n";
}
print "</select>";
print "<br><a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?action=add'>Add</a> || <a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?origname=$data[name]'>Edit</a>\n";
```

When someone clicks on "EDIT" link its showing up as: http://www.site.com?origname=
i want it to show up with the actual selected origname from the drop down list...
like:
http://www.site.com?origname=$selecteduser-fromdroplist

please help!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just make the form method = get?

```
<form id="select_name" action="" method="get">
    <select name="origname">
    <?php while ($data = dbResult($qh)): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $data[name]; ?>"><?php echo $data[name]; ?></option>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
    <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?action=add">Add</a> || <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit">
</form>
```

But as for why your code doesn't work, you're calling the $data[name'] item outside the while loop.

Comment: i need it as URL... not POST or GET